# Powershell check if user is local-user and have admin rights from username and password on local windows machine (Not active directory)

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to write a PowerShell script that takes username and password as input and then it checks if a user with those credentials exists and has admin rights.

Most of the questions or articles I have seen are about the active directory. I'm not talking about the active directory. I just want to check for a normal local machine.

I've tried this but I think this is about the active directory too.

```
$username = read-host 'Enter username'
$password = read-host 'Enter pass'

$computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$obj = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('machine', $computer)
$obj
$obj.ValidateCredentials($username, $password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need the password only the Userid using the microsoft.powershell.localaccounts module.

```
Function Test-Admin {

#Note: this requires that the module micorosft.powershell.localacounts
#      be loaded BEFORE the function is run as including a required directive
#      would cause the program to fail if the program loads the module!

  Param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [String] $UserToFind 
  )

$Admins = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators

If ( $Null -eq $($Admins.Name -like "*$UserToFind*") ) { 
        $Status = ' Not ' }
Else  { $Status = ' '     }

  "$UserToFind is" + $Status + "an Administrator of this Machine"

} #End Test-Admin
```

Sample runs:

```
PS> Test-Admin -UserToFind ImAnAdmin
ImAnAdmin is an Administrator of this Machine

PS> Test-Admin -UserToFind ImNotAnAdmin
ImNotAnAdmin is Not an Administrator of this Machine
```

Note: user names above replaced.

HTH

Comment: This script is working but the username and password are mandatory and then it must check if a local user of these credentials exists and have admin right then do certain things and you can assume these credentials are stored in a safe file. e.g. a user who doesn't have admin rights but wants to install software and requires admin rights, so he/she just have to run this script.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do? The script will tell you if the specified user has Administrative privilege's on the machine. What am I missing?

Comment: An organization/company has many computers and employees use them but they don't have admin rights on those machines. So if anyone wants to install a particular software and it requires admin right then this script runs and should by pass that using username and password saved in a file for instance. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: "So if Anyone", very dangerous! It seems a better solution would be to have a common Administrator account (same name and password) on every machine then individuals designated should be given this information to install software. Of course, once the account is setup on all machines if the machines are in a peer-to-peer lan this could be accomplished remotely via a powershell script.